# My program is not asking for the operator the second time

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>   

main(){
    int b,c,r,d;
    char a; 

    while(1){

     printf("Enter the operator\n");

          scanf("%c",&a);

          if(a=='+') d=1;
          if(a=='-') d=2;
          if(a=='&') d=3; 
          if(a=='|') d=4;
          if(a=='.') d=5;

          printf("Enter the operands\n");

          scanf("%d",&b);   
          scanf("%d",&c);

          switch(d){
            case 1:r=c+b;
            break;
            case 2:r=c-b;   
            break;
            case 3:r=c&b;
            break;
            case 4:r=c|b;
            break;
            case 5:exit(0);
            deafult:printf("Enter a valid operator");
        }
        printf("Result = %d\n",r);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the operator
+
Enter the operands
8
7
Result = 15
Enter the operator
Enter the operands
```

Comment: please someone answer what could be the reason

Answer (score 2):

That because of the function scanf width param "%c", after the 1st time loop, at line `scanf("%d",&c);`, like **+**, there's a **end-line** character in the input stream, then the second loop, scanf get the **end-line** character as the input and parse it to **a**;
To fix this, you can add a `scanf("%c");` line right after `scanf("%d",&c);`

Comment: why don't the subsequent scanf operations (to get operands) read that newline?

Comment: There're many ways to solve this kind of problems, so I think the reason is more important. By knowing that, we can come up with many solutions. Here is just a easiest way to fix this code without editing current code, in my opinion.

Comment: But that is not quite the reason. The newline is not left over from the first `scanf("%c"...`, but from the last `scanf("%d"...`.

Comment: Ah, sorry for my mistake. I mean it left from from the 1st time loop, at the line scanf("%d",&c), that why I add the line scan("%c") right after that. Thank sje397 again.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf("%d",...` will read a number (skipping whitespace beforehand) but leave the newline on the input stream. `scanf("%c",...` will read the first character, and does not skip whitespace.

One simple modification is to use

```
scanf(" %c", &a);
```

This will tell scanf to skip any whitespace before the character.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at
[scanf error in c while reading a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439385/scanf-error-in-c-while-reading-a-character)