# scanf error in c while reading a character

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char TurHare; 

    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%c",TurHare);
     printf("\nCharacter :%c", TurHare);
 }
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and then run the program the output is like :

```
w
Character : w
Character :
```

where w is the input from console.

It should appear like:

```
w
Character : w
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed &.

retry with

```
int main()
 {
char TurHare;   

    while(1)
    {
    scanf("%c",&TurHare);
    printf("\nCharacter :%c", TurHare);
    }

return 0;
}
```

I recommend getch,getche,getchar to use in case of character ,scanf will lead you to some buffering problem

Comment: still it doesn't work. i mean it should be & only but i pasted the code wrong here. Sorry for that.

Comment: try getch(),getchar(),getche() scanf shows some issues with  string and characters.  

char c = getchar();

Comment: yes when you press enter it queue up the enter key in stdin and next time it fetches in from stdin thus it doesn't work as it should

Answer (score 1):

Ok so Its because of return key which you enter after entering w. so once it reads w and other time it read the end of line character.

Answer (score 1):

There is an buffering-problem with scanf("%c"). Many people use fflush(stdin) to solve, but isnt ANSI.

```
void fflushstdin()
{
    int c;
    while( (c=getchar())=='\n' );
    if( c!=EOF )
        ungetc(c,stdin);
}

main()
{
    int TurHare;
    while( fflushstdin(), !feof(stdin)&&1==scanf("%c",&TurHare) )
    {
        printf("\nCharacter :%c", TurHare);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Break the loop with ^Z on Windows and ^D with Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Your program does what you tell it to do, it outputs the characters you type.

Now when you input `w` , look at what you're doing. You're hitting 2 keys. the `w` key , and `Enter` . That's the output you get, w and a newline(from the enter key). If you don't want that, do e.g.

```
char TurHare; 

while(1)
{
    if(scanf("%c",&TurHare) != 1) { //always check for errors
       break; //or some other error handling
    }

    if(c != '\n') { //or perhaps if(!isspace(c)) from <ctype.h>
      printf("\nCharacter :%c", TurHare);
      fflush(stdout);
    }
 }
```